# Illegal Stick Rule In NHL

Tags: rules, ice-hockey, nhl

The illegal stick rule has cobwebs on it. When was the last time a team was penalized for it, due to its blade being curved too much? Who were the teams? Back in the day some teams had a great eye for it.

Answer (score -1):

There is a similar question [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090310202849AA3IvsJ) on yahoo answers. Given this, I would say the last penalty was on the Senators Jason Spezza in 2009 called out against the Toronto Maple Leafs. You can view the video on youtube. A great stick measurement story is Marty McSorely in 1993. The blade measurements are clearly defined in the NHL rule book ([NHL Rule 10.5](http://www.nhl.com/nhl/en/v3/ext/rules/2014-2015-rulebook.pdf)), but it is an unwritten rule to not call it out.

Comment: Could you give some evidence that illegal stick penalties are deliberately not being called, as opposed to players just having legal sticks so there's nothing to call?

Answer (score -1):

After doing some research, the only information I could find was about Marty McSorley.

So, based on this research and in regards to answering your questions, I am going to use this [link](http://kings.nhl.com/club/news.htm?id=632932) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/%2A/http://kings.nhl.com/club/news.htm?id=632932)).

**Question 1: When was the last time a team was penalized for it, due to its blade being curved too much?**

> McSorley was penalized for using an illegally curved stick late in Game 2 of the 1993 Stanley Cup Final

**Question 2: Who were the teams?**

> Los Angeles Kings vs. Montreal Canadiens

Hope this helps.

Comment: As noted in Cody Glickman's answer, Jason Spezza was called for an illegal stick in 2009, so this answer is incorrect.